# error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'const BWAPI::UnitType *' to 'BWAPI::Type *'

Tags: c++, inheritance, syntax-error

im getting this error

error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'const BWAPI::UnitType *' to 'BWAPI::Type *'

at this line

```
this->generalType = &type;
```

what is the problem? since UnitType extends Type shouldn't be permitted?

```
class CombatEvent {

public:

    CombatEvent& setType(CombatEventType type);
    Type* getGeneralType() const;

private:
    UnitType unitType;
    Type* generalType;
}

// implementation

CombatEvent& CombatEvent::setUnitType(const UnitType type) {

    this->generalType = &type;
    this->unitType = type;

    return *this;
 }
```

Comment: It's in the CONST. 8 - ) Besides, you seem to be storing a pointer to a temporary variable, are you sure you want to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `const`. This should work. However, you are passing by value. You can pass by `const UnitType&` instead. This improves performance. Or course, remove the address-of operator in the offending line as well if you pass by reference.

Answer (score 1):

First, you're assigning an address of a const object to a pointer to a non-const object.

Second, even after you correct that, `this->generalType = &type` would store an address of the local function parameter which is destroyed on exiting the function. That is a very dangerous thing to do. The pointer would point to a garbage after leaning `setUnitType`.